# Saving Custom Form Item In WorkFlow Orchard

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms

I am currently having an issue where I am trying to do a check in a workflow before saving the custom form content item as a submission. Once the CreateAndPublish workflow is hit, it actually creates the item, but the field values aren't being saved properly.

Here is my workflow:

```
    public class CreateAndPublishActivity : Task {
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;

    public CreateAndPublishActivity(IContentManager contentManager) {
        _contentManager = contentManager;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public override bool CanExecute(WorkflowContext workflowContext, ActivityContext activityContext) {
        return true;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<LocalizedString> GetPossibleOutcomes(WorkflowContext workflowContext, ActivityContext activityContext) {
        return new[] { T("Done") };
    }

    public override IEnumerable<LocalizedString> Execute(WorkflowContext workflowContext, ActivityContext activityContext) {
        _contentManager.Create(workflowContext.Content.ContentItem, VersionOptions.Published);
        yield return T("Done");
    }

    public override string Name {
        get { return "CreateAndPublish"; }
    }

    public override LocalizedString Category {
        get { return T("Content Items"); }
    }

    public override LocalizedString Description {
        get { return T("Create and Publish the content item."); }
    }
}
```

The content item shows up under submissions, but none of the field values are there.